# Laravel 5 - Getting URL Parameters in Middleware on Resources

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say that I have a resource defined in my Routes as:

```
Route::resource('account', 'AccountController', ['only'=> ['index','update']]);
```

And then I have the `Middleware` attached to the `Controller` from within as:

```
public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('BeforeAccount', ['only' => ['update']]);
}
```

Let's say I want to access the uri parameter that happens after account (i.e. `example.com/account/2`) within my Middleware - how do I go about grabbing that variable?

Comment: It should be noted that this is an example - I do understand how poor of a security choice it would be to handle editing Accounts this way.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the following code to achieve that:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $account_id = $request->route()->parameter('accounts');

    //...
}
```

Since the `handle` method receives the `Request` object as the first argument. The `middleware` gets executed only after the route has been matched so the `Request` object contains the current route and no need to match the route again using `Route::getRoutes()->match($request)`.

Comment: Your answer definitely seems to be the best way to go about this.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this way you don't have to supply the \Request object:

```
Route::current()->parameter('parameter');
```

Comment: It's inside the `Middleware`'s `handle` method and the `Request` object is passed by `Laravel`.