# How can I use a different nomenclature for inputs in Laravel 5?

Tags: php, laravel, request

I've had a quick look into the Laravel 5 request object, and it looks like input params is found using:

```
$request->input('foo');
```

where foo would be either a GET variable (e.g. index.php?foo=bar) or a POST field.

What if I wanted to have my URL like so: `mywebsite.com/input1/val1/input2/val2`. Is it possible to access these via `$request->input('input1')`? Further, what if my POST is a JSON variable such as:

```
{
"input1" : "val1"
}
```

How would I access these parameters?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5 - Getting URL Parameters in Middleware on Resources](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31712218/laravel-5-getting-url-parameters-in-middleware-on-resources)

Answer (score 0):

to pass data in the URL you need to define your route, and this vars will be in the parameter of your controller

See [Dependency Injection & Route Parameters](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)

```
Route::put('user/{id}', 'UserController@update');
```

and the controller ...

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}
```

If your post is a jSON string you can access the same way with `$request`
And see **Retrieving JSON Input Values** in the same link

If you need the 'id' in your middleware try to access with the `$request`

```
 $request->id
```

[acess the parameters in the middleware](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/how-to-get-url-parameters-at-middleware?page=1)

OR

You can use

`$request->route()->parameter('id');`

Comment: I'm trying to access my URL data in middleware. I can't access /user/{id} in $request->input('user'), if that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

We can access like this, Hope this helps you
This is my route

```
Route::get('/group/{name}/{id}', 'GroupController@getGroups');
```

And controller method

```
public function getGroups($name, $id)
{    
  echo $name; //url parameter name
  echo $id;
}
```